# Hide input field if selected details value is null in angular 4

Tags: angular

> - whats my question is some response has serviceName value some response don't have serviceName value if i select one of the category if serviceName is null it is showing error as **" Cannot read property 'serviceName' of undefined"**
> - what i need is if selected value is null it should hide that field only if selected value is there it should display details how to achieve it
> - Any suggestion will be accepted thank you.

```
<div class="custom-form">
     <div class="col-6 col-lg-4" *ngFor="let cat of values">
        <div class="tab-wrapper v1">
            <div class="list">
              <div class="item" >
                <div class=tab-btn (click)="onSelect(cat)"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{cat.categoryName}}</a></div>
                <div class="tab-content">
                  <div class=" fl-wrap filter-tags" *ngIf="selected">
                     <input type="checkbox" name="check1">
                        <label for="check-a">{{selected?.categoryServicemodel[0].serviceName}} </label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="check2">
                        <label for="check-b">{{selected?.categoryServicemodel[1].serviceName}}   </label>                              
                   </div>                    
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

> This is my component.html  file
>
> this is my component.ts

```
export class Component{
 selected: any ={};
    constructor(private router: Router, private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader, private ngZone: NgZone, private service: PostGetService) {
   this.service.getAllCategories()
       .subscribe((categories:any )=>{
       // console.log(categories.json().length);
         this.values = categories.json();
         console.log(this.values);
       })
        onSelect(category){
        this.selected = category;
        console.log(category);
    }
  }
```

> this is my response 
>    [image: Response image]

Comment: Just add `{{selected?.categoryServicemodel[0].serviceName}}` inside a `*ngIf`, with `selected?.categoryServicemodel[0]?.serviceName` as a condition. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because of the attempt to access the `serviceName` property although not all `categoryServicemodel` arrays contain two elements.
The problem can be solved by not hard coding the index in the template but using a `*ngFor`.

Because the `isActive` flag is not a boolean, the checkbox is not directly bindable via banana-box syntax `[(ngModel)]`.

The initial value can be converted to a boolean with double negation '!!' and bound to the checkbox with [ngModel]="!!category.isActive". 
With every click on the checkbox this must now be converted to a number and assigned to the model. `(ngModelChange)="category.isActive = $event ? 1 : 0"`

I recommend to adjust the type of the `isActive` flag to boolean. This will make things easier.

```
...
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class=" fl-wrap filter-tags" *ngIf="selected">
        <label *ngFor="let category of selected.categoryServicemodel; let i = index">
            <input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="!!category.isActive" (ngModelChange)="category.isActive = $event ? 1 : 0" name="indx{{i}}"> {{category.serviceName}}
        </label>                      
    </div>    
</div>
...
```

Comment: i need one more help as mentioned above i need to display all details . . but now not on selection onInit() i need to display all details in a card for ex. header should be category name under that both service name and service description should be there